# I cannot save a picture link from a facebook account

Tags: django

I am trying get a picture link from a facebook account but get this message:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: 
user_profile.user_id
```

I can see a picture link in console, but I cannot save it in user profile.

here is my model.py when I'm trying to do that.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from allauth.account.signals import user_signed_up, user_logged_in


from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialAccount
import hashlib


try:
    from django.utils.encoding import force_text
except ImportError:
    from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode as force_text


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name='userprofile')

    city = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    about = models.TextField(blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars/', verbose_name='Images', 
    blank=True)

    sound = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    points = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    energy = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    avatar_url = models.URLField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_profile'
        verbose_name = 'Profile'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Profiles'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.userprofile.save()


#@receiver(user_logged_in)
@receiver(user_signed_up)
def set_initial_user_names(request, user, sociallogin=None, **kwargs):
    preferred_avatar_size_pixels = 25

    if sociallogin:
        if sociallogin.account.provider == 'facebook':     
            picture_url = "http://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture?width={1}&height={1}".format(
                sociallogin.account.uid, preferred_avatar_size_pixels)

        profile = UserProfile(user=user, avatar_url=picture_url)
        #profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
        #profile.avatar_url = picture_url
        profile.save()
```

If I am doing like that at the end:

```
    #profile = UserProfile(user=user, avatar_url=picture_url)
    profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
    profile.avatar_url = picture_url
    profile.save()
```

I am not gettin any message in the console, but user profile doesn't save.

Comment: The error is stating that that user's pk already exist in the db. Did you subclass the user model?

Comment: No, I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line `profile = UserProfile(user=user, avatar_url=picture_url)` is causing the problem as you are trying to create a new instance of profile which already exists. The profile becomes unique because of `OneToOne` field in your `UserProfile` model.

And you don't need to get the user from the database because `set_initial_user_names` function is already passing the registered user to you as a parameter. So just do `user.userprofile`. Then you can just update the user with new information.

Also I would suggest you to download the picture from the url provided and then save it in your image field of your model like this:

```
 import urllib
 from django.core.files import File 

 # for python 2: result = urllib.urlretrieve(picture_url)[0]      
 result = urllib.request.urlretrieve(picture_url)[0] # for python 3
 user.userprofile.avatar.save('test.jpg', File(open(result, 'rb')))
 user.userprofile.save()
```

Comment: @mikeru did that helped you ?

Comment: I'm sorry for late reply. I have just done it. Thank you so so so much.